# How to selecting files based on text file and creating bat file?

Tags: file, batch-file, select, text

I need to select files from a folder. These spesific filenames is listed in a text file. How can I make a bat file to run for this purpose?

Comment: Welcome, please show us what you have tried?

Comment: I am trying to do something  FOR ... and get the first row in a textfile.(read it)... the DO ... copy /path/path/firstrow.file /newpath/newpath/

Comment: Where did your answer go?? I cant read the first clue I got here. It is gone? Where can I find it?

Comment: I am trying similar to this: Examples

Copy the files listed in a text file to a new destination: 

FOR /f "delims=" %%G in (files.txt) DO copy "\\source\folder\%%G" "H:\destination\%%G"   but the filenames in the text.file does not contain the extention. I need to add the extention with doing to copying. How do I do this?

Comment: Y:\a>FOR /f "delims=*" %%G in (liste.txt) DO echo %%G
%%G was unexpected at this time.

Y:\a>FOR /f "delims=*" %%G in (Y:/a/liste.txt) DO echo %%G
%%G was unexpected at this time.

Y:\a>FOR /f "delims=*" %%G in (Y:/a/liste.txt) DO echo %%G
%%G was unexpected at this time.

Y:\a>more liste.txt
number1
number2
number3

Y:\a>FOR /f "delims=" %%G in (files.txt) DO copy "Y:\a\%%G*.all" "Y:\b\%%G*.all"
%%G was unexpected at this time.

Y:\a>

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the information you've incorrectly added to the comment area, as opposed to your question *(by way of [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54632579/edit))*.

From a batch file:

```bat
@CD /D "Y:\a" 2>Nul||Exit/B
@For /F UseBackDelims^=^ EOL^= %%A In ("liste.txt")Do @Copy /Y "%%A*" "Y:\b">Nul 2>&1
```

or:

```bat
@CD /D "Y:\a" 2>Nul||Exit/B
@For /F UseBackDelims^=^ EOL^= %%A In ("liste.txt")Do @Copy /Y "%%A*" "..\b">Nul 2>&1
```

However, it appears from your comments that you're trying to do this from the command prompt, *despite the [batch-file] tag and no [cmd] tag*.

Using your last example command as a basis, from the command prompt you can use either:

```bat
C:\Users\trollgrammer>CD /D Y:\a
Y:\a>For /F "Delims=" %G In (files.txt) Do @Copy /Y "%G*" "Y:\b"
```

…or

```bat
C:\Users\trollgrammer>CD /D Y:\a
Y:\a>For /F "Delims=" %G In (files.txt) Do @Copy /Y "%G*" "..\b"
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Is it possible to search recursively for a file in the command?

Comment: Did my answer provide a solution to your question based upon the code you posted in the comment area? If it did, then please mark it as accepted, otherwise, please copy the information from the comment to your question, _by way of [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54632579/edit)_, and significantly improve it such that members can consider expanding upon what I've posted. It seems as if you're asking a new question, _i.e. about something you didn't mention in your question or subsequent comments_. If this is a new question, then ask it as such, _don't expect me to provide a new solution!_